Rnmapbox does not scroll vertically only horizontally in ScrollView
After updating React-native 0.70 to 0.76, rnmapbox stopped scrolling in ScrollView.
Removing scrollView is not an option, because there is content, because there is content that needs to be displayed. How to fix this behavior, do I need to get into android/ios folders?
